# A List of all flutter Icons

Tags: flutter, icons

I am facing difficulty searching for appropriate flutter icons. Is there any website or any source from where I can get the list of all the icons available for flutter?

Comment: https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Icons

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Default Material Icons: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html

Flutter custom icons generator: https://www.fluttericon.com/

FontAwesomeIcons: https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter

Icon Forest: https://pub.dev/packages/icon_forest

Icon Sax: https://pub.dev/packages/iconsax

Ion Icons: https://pub.dev/packages/ionicons

Unicons: https://pub.dev/packages/unicons

Line Icons: https://pub.dev/packages/line_icons

Answer (score 25):

From the link below you have all Material Symbols and Icons from Google. No need to add a dependency as the standard Flutter lib includes them already:

https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Icons

For example, the search icon is like this:

```dart
Icon(
  Icons.search,
),
```

---

There is the [`ionicons`](https://pub.dev/packages/ionicons) too, a complete lib with 1.3K icons. And the list of them all is here: https://ionic.io/ionicons

---

Also, if you'd like to change the launcher icons a good place is the link below. You can design Android, iOS, web, macOS... icons super easy.

https://icon.kitchen/

Comment: I find the link here much more useful that the "Default Material Icons" provided by the answer marked as solution as it can be filtered in real time in groups of icons.

Comment: I'm finding that some of the google-icons are not available within Flutter as expected, such as work_update.  So I'm wondering how google-icons could be added to Flutter's collection of material icons.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Search 160k+ icons from all pub.dev packages https://pub.dev/packages/icon_forest

[image: demo]

It contains most of the popular open-source icon libraries.

Comment: this lib is under maintained, some dependices too old, not suggest

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above answers... you can find a pdf cheat sheet here if you want to print perhaps..
[Material icons pdf cheatsheet](https://creativealive.com/pdf-cheat-sheet-for-material-icons-by-google/)

Answer (score 2):

Flutter depending on the theme, by default comes with icons,...

Search Default Material:https://materialdesignicons.com/